# set function with unique pointer is giving error c2280

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

When I try to run the below code, I am getting this error message:

> Error C2280 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

How can I fix this error?

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>

class A {
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vecvec;
public:
    A();
    void setA(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
            vecvec.push_back(vec.at(i));
        }
    }
    void printInfo() {
        for (int i = 0; i < vecvec.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << *vecvec.at(i) << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    A example;

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec;


    std::unique_ptr<int> ptrA1 = std::make_unique<int>(5);
    std::unique_ptr<int>ptrA2 = std::make_unique<int>(6);


    vec.push_back(std::move(ptrA1));
    vec.push_back(std::move(ptrA2));

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << *vec.at(i) << std::endl;
    }


    example.setA(std::move(vec));
    example.printInfo();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i need to set field through void function how can do that without pass the vectors by values?

Comment: Have you heard of reference parameters? Also, you _cannot_ copy a `unique_ptr`

Comment: You *move* the pointers into the vector `vec` in the `main` function. But not in the `setA` function. Did someone else write the `main` function for you?

Comment: should i use like that `example.setA((vec));` ? it gives same error too

Comment: In the `main` function you have e.g. `vec.push_back(std::move(ptrA1));` I.e. you move `ptrA1` into the vector. This is correct. But in the `setA` function you have `vecvec.push_back(vec.at(i));` which attempt to *copy* the unique pointer. This is wrong.

Comment: so what i need to use instead of using `vecvec.push_back(vec.at(i));` i am expected to set class vector  field or vector of unique pointer field.

Comment: You need to *move* the pointers into `vecvec` just like you move the pointers into `vec`.

Comment: i also tried this one `vecvec.push_back(std::move(vec.at(i)));` in setA function, but it gives same error

Comment: Strange, [it works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/9abWh6ans) with `std::move` in `setA`.

Comment: With that said, why don't you move the whole vector? As in `vecvec = std::move(vec);`

Comment: On an unrelated note I suggest you learn about [range-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). Will make it easier to iterate over your containers.

Comment: when i change unique_ptr to shared_ptr  it works, otherwise it gives same error. thanks for suggestion (range-based for loops) i will take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to fix with change this line:

```cpp
vecvec.push_back(std::move(vec.at(i)));
```

You need to move the `unique_ptr` but not the default the copy behavior, `unique_ptr` is move-only but not copyable. For `shared_ptr`, it's copyable and moveable, so if you change it to `shared_ptr` it works.

By the way, you have forgotten to add a constructor definition:

```cpp
A() = default;
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7oYG6o5ar)